# Probability of having exactly one empty container

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What's the probability that if we distribute N letters

among N drawers and presume that every single

configuration is equally likely (saturation is at

least 0 and at most N) then a single drawer

will be found empty?

//////////////////////

My progress so far:

Total number of cases: $N^{N}$

*Reasoning:
It's the implication of the saturation condition.*

/////////////////

The number of favorable configurations:

$2 \cdot \binom{N}{2}\cdot (N - 2)!$

*Reasoning:*

*I can choose $2$ drawers out of $N$ drawers in $\binom{N}{2}$ ways.*

*These two drawers serve as the empty one and the one containing two letters.*

*The factor $2$ is to consider the relative location of the two drawers.*

*$(N - 2)!$ is to take the permutation of the remaining drawers into account.*

///////////////////

I feel like something is mistaken.

Question: What's the route of correctness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $N^N$ looks reasonable for the total number of equally likely arrangements.

One approach to the second part is to say that we choose $2$ of the $N$ items ${N\choose 2}$ ways and a drawer to put them in $N$ ways and another drawer to be empty $N-1$ ways and then organise the remaining $N-2$ drawers and $N-2$ items $(N-2)!$ ways, giving $${N\choose 2}N(N-1)\,(N-2)! = \frac{N(N-1)}2N!$$ possibilities, which we then divide by $N^N$ to get a probability.

- For $N=2$ this gives $\frac12$
- For $N=3$ this gives $\frac23$
- For $N=4$ this gives $\frac9{16}$
- For $N=5$ this gives $\frac{48}{125}$

which seems plausible

Answer (score 5):

Favorable Configurations:

$ \displaystyle 2 \cdot \binom{N}{2}\cdot \binom{N}{2} \cdot(N - 2)!$

We choose two drawers, one of them will hold two letters and one will be empty. Remaining $(N-2)$ drawers will hold one letter each. Now we choose two letters that will go into the drawer selected to keep two letters. Letters in remaining drawers can be arranged in $(N-2)!$ ways.